# Android Java Base64.encodeToString out of memory issue when encode byte array to base64 string

Tags: java, android, base64, encode

I got a memory leak issues at Base64.encodeToString when trying to convert an image to base64 string. Typically the image size is 200x200 pixels. This task takes place in every 2-3 seconds.
Sometimes, the image size may reach 1920x1080 in 200 seconds.
The app crashes after 10 minutes or so...

```
public String getBase64(ByteBuffer fullFrameImage, int width, int height, android.graphics.Rect roi) {
        fullFrameImage.rewind();
        fullFrameImage.get(imageInBuffer, 0, imageInBuffer.length);
        try {
            yuvImage = new YuvImage(imageInBuffer, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
            outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(roi, 100, outStream);
            tempImageByteArray = outStream.toByteArray();
            base64_string = Base64.encodeToString(tempImageByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            outStream.reset();
            outStream = null;
            yuvImage = null;
            tempImageByteArray=null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            base64_string="";
            logDebug("getBase64 Error: " + e.getMessage(),true);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The app crashes with the following exception:

```
java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars(Native Method)
java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars(StringFactory.java:121)
java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:106)
java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:65)
android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
com.ttn.usbcamera.view.CameraActivity.getBase64(CameraActivity.java:1668)
com.ttn.usbcamera.view.CameraActivity$1$2.onSuccess(CameraActivity.java:325)
com.ttn.usbcamera.view.CameraActivity$1$2.onSuccess(CameraActivity.java:294)
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:724)
exception：Failed to allocate a 1729988 byte allocation with 1695360 free bytes and 1655KB until OOM
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap
Processing large images are likely to introduce this issue every now and then.

Comment: @Rahul Shukla, So you say the memory problem in not base64 encoding related but with handling bitmaps?

Comment: @RahulShukla I don't aim at displaying bitmaps. My goal is to get the base64 string of the image.

Comment: The memory constraints are not in displaying but decoding the image.